# How to download file with same name in Servlet and using html and javascript

Tags: java, javascript, html, servlets

I am using servlets to make a downloading program.

```
enter code here package com.lara;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet
 {
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException,IOException
   {

 // new code -- start
   String filename = request.getParameter("ojdbc");
    filename = filename + ".jar";
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=\"" + filename +        "\"");


   ServletContext ct = getServletContext();
 InputStream in = ct.getResourceAsStream("/bookCode.jar");
 int read=0;
   byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
  OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
  while((read=in.read(bytes))!=-1)
  {
   os.write(bytes,0,read);
  }
 os.flush();
   os.close();
 }
}
```

//
i want to use anchor tab in html..so by clicking it i can get the same name of the file which is in my case coming null..but works..using other method...In short i want code.jar name through anchor link Can anyone help me..

Answer (score 0):

This might work... try adding :

```
response.setContentType("application/x-download");
```